# Modelling where both the DV and IV change over time

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data

In the typical repeated measures problem, the DV changes over time but the IVs stay the same. In my problem, I have an IV that changes.  I cannot be completely explicit because the problem is sensitive but here is an explanation.

I have 5 subjects.  Each was repeatedly (over a great many trials) told to do something or not do it. The IV is whether they were told to do it or not (dichotomous).  The DV is whetehr they did it or not (also dichotomous).

We are not interested in intersubject differences or in the effects of time; the simple method was just to ignore these and do a table anc chisquare.  But different people might be better or worse at following the instructions, so I thought a multilevel model would be good.  But once I started trying to code, I realized I did not know how to do this.

I have SAS and R available.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you make more explicit the sense in which you think of the IV as changing over time? Your description does not seem to distinguish that situation from one in which the IV is systematically (but randomly) varied as in any designed experiment.  Are you actually thinking of the *regression coefficients* as changing over time?

Comment: The IV changes over time in that, for each person, they are told at time 1 "blink" at time 2 "blink", at time 3 "don't blink" and so on for many hundred time points. So, for the 5 subjects we have well over 1,000 pairs of what they were told to do and what they did.  If it was 1 subject or if it was 1,000 subjects, I would just look at regular methods for the relationship of two dichotomous variables. But we have 5 subjects.  I think I need to account for that. But perhaps not.

Comment: I still don't see where time enters unless you are worried about a "learning curve" effect.  But that has nothing to do with changing the IV over time and everything to do with a varying *response* in the subjects over time.

Comment: I don't care about the effects of time, but I was worried about the independence of the data.  But maybe I am inventing a problem where none exist.

Comment: Why not test the independence? Something as simple as a Durbin-Watson statistic (obtained after fitting the model, but computed separately for each subject) could be informative.